# E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptitude:4: Extra junk at end of file

Tags: apt

ubuntu 14.04 Update manager: “A problem occurred when checking for the updates
that is what appear when using terminal

Comment: Post the content of the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptitude`

Comment: Aptitude::Get-Root-Command "sudo:/usr/bin/sudo";
Acquire::Languages "none"

Comment: Close voters: Read the comments. It works for the OP means it's not unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Each line in the 00aptitude file should end with a semicolon character.

Run the command [`man apt.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt.conf) from the terminal and under the **`DESCRIPTION`** and **`SYNTAX`** headings it says:

> apt.conf is the main configuration file for the APT suite of tools, all tools make use of the configuration file and a common command-line parser to provide a uniform environment.
>   ...
>   APT::Get::Assume-Yes "true";. The quotation marks and trailing semicolon are required.

To edit the `00aptitude` file use the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptitude
```

Edit the `00aptitude` file so that instead of:

```
Aptitude::Get-Root-Command "sudo:/usr/bin/sudo"; 
Acquire::Languages "none"
```

It is changed so that it is:

```
Aptitude::Get-Root-Command "sudo:/usr/bin/sudo"; 
Acquire::Languages "none";
```

The only thing you have to change is to add a semicolon character to the end of the second line.

Nano is very easy to use. The instructions for using nano editor are always found at the bottom of every page. The only two nano keyboard shortcuts that you need to know are for WriteOut and Exit. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file being edited. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Comment: it shows No manual entry for apt-conf

Comment: Actually it was my fault. The correct command to see the manual page for apt.conf from the terminal should have been `man apt.conf`. Not that it makes any real difference, since the only purpose of that command is to show the manual page for apt.conf. How frustrating! All I really wanted to say was to make sure that all of the lines in the 00aptitude file end in a **;** character.